# Error message shows even when answer is valid

Tags: python, sys

This is my first course in coding and I don't really know how to use file=sys.stderr correctly.

I am trying to get a y or n input from the user and only have the error message show when the answer is neither of those.

This is my code:

```
aches = input("Aches (y/n): ")
 if aches != 'y' or 'n':
 print ("Error!",file=sys.stderr)
```

aches= aches.casefold()

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It's `if aches != 'y' and aches != 'n':`.
`if aches != 'y' or 'n'` is evaluated to `if (aches != 'y') or ('n')` == `if (aches != 'y') or true`.
I guess what you're looking for is `if aches not in ['y', 'n']:`.
A better approach would be `if aches.lower() not in ['y', 'n']:`, which will not consider `'Y'` and `'N'` as error.